# Como puedo ingresar campos con los mismos ids para una galería de imágenes en PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax, phpmyadmin

Estoy creando un proyecto de bienes raíces, donde tengo que enlistar las imágenes de las propiedades y no cuentro una forma más fácil creo de tener un arreglo con los mismos id's de las propiedades...

El problema es que ya no se como se puede repetir los ids en mysql con php, ya que no se si será igual que con las imagenes... las imagenes cuando toma siempre la ultima cuando tomo de varias.

Aqui el codigo php

```
if ($_POST['registro'] == 'nuevo') {

$titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
 $id_propiedad = $_POST['propiedad'];

foreach ($_FILES['archivo_imagen']['tmp_name'] as $clave => $tmp_name) {

$directorio = "../images/propiedades/";

if (!is_dir($directorio)) {
  mkdir($directorio, 0755, true);
}

//Imagenes
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo_imagen']['tmp_name'][$clave], $directorio . $_FILES['archivo_imagen']['name'][$clave])) {
  $imagen_url = $_FILES['archivo_imagen']['name'][$clave];
  $imagen_resultado = "Se subió correctamente";
} else {
  $respuesta = array(
    'respuesta' => error_get_last()
  );
}
 }
try {

$stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO galeria (titulo, url_imagen, propiedad_id   ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?) ');
$stmt->bind_param("ssi", $titulo, $imagen_url, $id_propiedad);
$stmt->execute();

$id_insertado = $stmt->insert_id;
if ($stmt->affected_rows) {
  $respuesta = array(
    'respuesta' => 'correcto',
    'id_insertado' => $id_insertado,
    'resultado_imagen' => $imagen_resultado,
  );
} else {
  $respuesta = array(
    'respuesta' => 'error'
  );
}
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
} catch (Exception $e) {
  $respuesta = array(
    'respuesta' => $e->getMessage()
  );
}

die(json_encode($respuesta));
}
```

Obviamente el codigo html contiene el name con arreglo del file

Comment: No se entiende, necesita redacción.

Comment: No se entiende tu pregunta, primero explica lo que necesitas exactamente, se explícito

Comment: tu pregunta no se entiende cuando te refieres a los ids, esta refiriéndote a la primary key de cada registro o al nombre de la imagen?

Comment: Cada imagen debe tener su propio ID (único) y una columna adicional para asociarla con la propiedad a la que pertenece.

Comment: Lo que necesito es saber como asociar una galería de imágenes a una propiedad, es decir si tengo 20 imagenes que le pertenezcan a una sola propiedad, todas las imagenes con el mismo primery key.... o como puedo hacer una galería de imagenes perteneciente a una propiedad ??

Answer (score 0):

Hombre bro, solo necesitas dos tablas, una que diga "Fotos" y otra "Galeria".

TBL_Fotos= ID_Foto, Foto,(FK)ID_Galeria.

TBL_Galeria=ID_Galeria,Nombre_Galeria.

eso es todo, ahi estas diciendo. que una galeria puede tener muchas fotos, primero creas la "Galeria" con sus nombres, y luego al momento de agregarlas solo colocas el id de la "galeria" al cual pertenecen.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).